# Py program gives an error if I dont open it with interactive shell

Tags: python

I 've a porgram called searchMachine.py that if I run it straight from IDLE (F5..)it works just fine, but If I run it by just clicking on searchMachine.py it works untill somepoint and then I get an error. See below.
Thanks for any input you could give me.
By the way, any idea how I can make this chrome work in silent? for example minimized?

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

    print('Please type the machine name.')
    machinename = input()
    print('')
    print('Thank you.')
    print('')
    print('Results will show below.')
    print('')

    path_to_chromedriver = 'C:\python34\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe' # change path as needed
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
    url = 'http://app.corp'
    browser.get(url)



    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/form/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[5]/input[1]").send_keys(machinename)

    browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=\"submit\"]').click() # working to press submit

    xpath = '/html/body/div[4]/form/center[2]/table/thead'
    for i in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
        print (i.text)
    xpath = '/html/body/div[4]/form/center[2]/table/tbody/tr'
    for i in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
        print (i.text)

    browser.close() 

import os
os.system("c:/code/close_chrome_driver.bat")
```

error is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the unicode character `▾` or `U+25BE BLACK DOWN-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE` cannot be written into Windows console window, as it does not have a match in the `CP850` character set as used by *your* Windows console.

Now, Python croaks loudly when it cannot print the correct value. You could set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to say `cp850:ignore` which would make the Python process ignore errors; or you can print to `stderr` instead of `stdout`, which would use the `backslashescape` error handling.

Comment: I think I understood, could you give me a tip on how to create such varibale with my code above? thanks a lot.

Comment: some thing like this: print(data.decode('utf-8').encode('cp850','replace').decode('cp850')) ?

Comment: I used ->   print (i.text, file=sys.stderr)  but somehow the cmd windows is closing after it? Shouldnt this fix the issue? thank you again